# Editing css properties of MUI Icons

Tags: css, material-ui

Can somebody help me how to change the css property of mui icons so that i can assign a perticular color when the icon is on focus...I have used the icons in header and am rendering specific pages under them so for differentiating which page is currently active i want to assign different color on focus.
Here is my code-

```
<PeopleOutlineIcon onClick={()=>navigate('/dashboard/candidates')}
                sx={{
                  color:"black",
                  fontSize: 40,
                  cursor: "pointer",
                  "& :focus": {color:"blue"}
                }}
               />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/iconbutton-hover-focus-cnexr?fontsize=14&file=/demo.js) will be useful to you.

You should use the 'IconButton' component from MUI to wrap the Icon. And apply the styles in the IconButton to make it work on focus.

Basically, the property is called '&.Mui-focusVisible'.

Comment: Please don't use external links to show code, as they aren't guaranteed to be accessible by all users. Instead, please [edit] your answer to include the relevant code as [formatted text](/editing-help#code).

Comment: I tried the method you mentioned its working for "hover" but I want the icon to remain in blue color after I have clicked on it once untill i click on another icon

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to add `&` to access [pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) of the MUI icon. Second, I think `:focus` pseudo-class is mainly used for `<input/>` elements. What you are looking for is either `:hover` or `:active`.
You can try these classes this way

```
<PeopleOutlineIcon onClick={()=>navigate('/dashboard/candidates')}
     sx={{
        color:"black",
        fontSize: 40,
        cursor: "pointer",
        ":active": {color:"blue"},
        ":hover": {color:"blue"},
      }}
  />
```

Comment: i tried your method and the color is changing to blue when i click the icon but it is reverting back to black when i release the click, I want it to remain in chnages state untill i click on another icon